# Testing with EmbeddedKafka and asserting on the events published

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-kafka

I am writing an integration test for a SpringBoot application and I need to assert that two messages are sent. I am trying to avoid mocking and use @EmbededKafka instead. I have created this consumer for the test package only:

```java
@Component
public class StudentCreatedTestConsumer {
    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Setter
    private Runnable afterReceive = () -> {};

    @Getter
    private List<Map<String, String>> events = new ArrayList<>();

    public void reset() {
        afterReceive = () -> {};
        events = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @KafkaListener(topics = "student.created")
    public void receive(ConsumerRecord<String, String> evt) {
        events.add(parseHashMap(evt.value()));
        afterReceive.run();
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private HashMap<String, String> parseHashMap(String evt) {
        TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>> typeRef = new TypeReference<>() {};
        return mapper.readValue(evt, typeRef);
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> getEventsSortedBy(String key) {
        return events.stream()
                .sorted(comparing(e -> e.get(key)))
                .toList();
    }
}
```

And I'm using it in my tests like this:

```java
@Test
void test() throws Exception {
    //given
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2); // will wait for 2 events
    testConsumer.setAfterReceive(latch::countDown);

    // when
    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/students")
                    .content(...)
                    .contentType(contentType))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

    //then
    latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    List<Map<String, String>> events = testConsumer.getEventsSortedBy("name");
    assertThat(events).hasSize(2);
    assertThat(events.get(0))
            .containsKey("studentId")
            .containsEntry("name", "anna")
            .containsEntry("age", "27");
    //and
    assertThat(events.get(1))
            .containsKey("studentId")
            .containsEntry("name", "bobby")
            .containsEntry("age", "25");
}
```

Now I was wondering, would it be a better way? I am using this `CountDownLatch` to awaits for the first 2 events, but what if the app produces 3 events? Is there a better way of testing this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Awaitility](http://www.awaitility.org/) instead of blocking for a fixed time.
You could add methods for waiting for an event to your consumer:

```java
public Map<String, String> awaitEventMatching(final Predicate<Map<String, String>> eventCondition) {
    return awaitEventMatching(eventCondition, Durations.TEN_SECONDS);
}

public Map<String, String> awaitEventMatching(final Predicate<Map<String, String>> eventCondition,
                                              final Duration timeout) {
    return await(String.format("%s on topic %s", eventName, topic))
            .atMost(timeout)
            .pollInterval(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .until(() -> events.stream().filter(eventCondition).findFirst(), Optional::isPresent)
            .orElseThrow();
}

public void awaitEventsMatching(final Predicate<List<Map<String, String>>> eventsCondition) {
    awaitEventsMatching(eventsCondition, Durations.TEN_SECONDS);
}

public void awaitEventsMatching(final Predicate<List<Map<String, String>>> eventsCondition,
                                final Duration timeout) {
    await(String.format("%s on topic %s", eventName, topic))
            .atMost(timeout)
            .pollInterval(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .until(() -> eventsCondition.test(events));
}
```

By this means you could wait for a single event matching a given criteria (`awaitEventMatching`) or check multiple events (`awaitEventsMatching`).
Note that the `awaitEventMatching` returns the matched event for further assertions.

More on Awaitility on [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/awaitility-testing).

Comment: thanks  for reaching out, i will look into it